# linkbutton not posting back in IE7 for all child elements

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-7, linkbutton

In the following code, in IE7 clicking on the "click here" text instigates the server onclick event, but clicking on the img does not?

```
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbFoodSwapCourse" OnClick="LoadStepTwo_Click" runat="server">
                                        <span class="foodSwapBigCourseLink" runat="server">
                                            <span class="foodSwapBigCourseImage"><img src="images/star.jpg" /></span>
                                            <span class="foodSwapBigCourseText">click here</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tag this as an ASP or .NET issue.  Anything that begins with the < asp: is specific to those languages, and not standard HTML.